# Xcode 3 -> 4 causing errors

Tags: xcode, macos-carbon

I have a Carbon-based project that compiles on XCode 3, but fails on XCode 4.
It can't seem to find any Carbon or QT functions, even though I've included 
 and #include

I get lots of errors like this:
No member named 'InitCursor' in the global namespace

I tried re-adding in the Carbon.framework from the System/Library/Frameworks folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `InitCursor` function](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuickDraw_Ref/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/InitCursor), along with [pretty much everything else in QuickDraw](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuickDraw_Ref/), was removed in Lion. You will need to remove your uses of all removed APIs, and probably replace most of them with more modern replacements.

This is a non-trivial task, but it is necessary if you want to build with modern tools and target current and future versions of Mac OS X.

It's been a long time coming, too; QuickDraw has been deprecated for years.

Much of Carbon is still supported, and you should find that you are not getting errors about those APIs.

You mention Qt; I've heard that there is a Cocoa version of Qt now.

Comment: So I need to compile on 3.2? and never on 4? I may do Cocoa in the future by now it's too big a job and have people depending on the app.

Comment: You answer got me thinking though and I changed the base SDK to 10.6 and got things to compile now, so thanks so much for your help! Unfortunately, it says that it's built, but I can't find the app anywhere. Any idea how to get it to emerge from the morass?

Comment: @user123777: Either open the Derived Data folder from the Project Settings, or right-click on the build product in the Products group and choose “Show in Finder”. If you're building a release, use the Archive command and then use the Organizer's “Show in Finder” command; the app is inside the .xcarchive (and you should keep the whole xcarchive, as it includes debug symbols).

Comment: @user123777: Are you testing on Snow Leopard? Given that the functions are listed as not available on Lion, it's possible that your app may not run on Lion machines even after you successfully build it.

Comment: They sure do hide things now. It runs in Lion fine. Thanks for all your help here!